# LTM4625 Regulator

Tags: switching-regulator

I am using LTM4625 Step-Down DC/DC µModule Regulator.VIN:12V and Vout:3.3V @5A. My circuit draw 2.9A current from LTM4625. Does my regulator hot? How can I calculate regulator's heat?

https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/LTM4625.pdf

Answer (score 2):

There are usually some efficiency charts but in this case, LT/ADI has provided not just only these charts but also power loss at various input and output voltages.

For example, in your case, power loss at 3.3V output (figure 10, page 17):

[image]

For 12V input and 3.3V output, the power loss is roughly 1W at 2.9A load.

From there on, you can consult the Thermal Considerations section in the datasheet to estimate how hot does the LTM4625 heat up.

Comment: Thermal considerations summarized on datasheet page 18, table 5, line 1: 12V->3.3V. no heatsink, no airflow, 22 degree celcius per watt thermal resistance. If the thing is supposed to run at room temperature like most common things, sounds totally ok